# WindowBuilderPro V/S Matisse4MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin

Any comments on which of these GUI development plugins is better.

I have tried out Matisse on [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/), and I did like it.

Is [WindowBuilderPro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) (which I have not tried out yet) a better call than Matisse?

Comment: Which IDE do you prefer: Eclipse or NetBeans?

Comment: I second trashgod comment on that one. Besides, in terms of GUI design, your best bet is to hand-code it, not use any GUI builder tool (there's lots of SO questions about that, with answers explaining why GUI builders are bad).

Comment: @trashgod   i prefer using eclipse...

Comment: As @murat notes, that significantly impacts your choice. In either case, @jfpoilpret is right: _first_ learn carpentry, _then_ select a power saw. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowBuilder runs on Eclipse where Matisse runs on NetBeans. The IDE you are using (or you need to use) is the game changer in this case. However i feel WindowBuilder is a new and promising tool where matisse is a stable and proven one.

Comment: well i checked n saw that an eclipse version of matisse was developed (here)[link](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/swing-gui-designer)) ....but it seems that this project was abandoned. i was unable download it from the official site

Comment: yep, eclipse for matisse was a nice start but i believe better to use something really developer for eclipse to stay on the stable side.